# Powershell - Elevation Loses Current Directory

Tags: powershell

One problem leads to another! User help just fixed one issue, which led to another as I continued working on this script. My script runs a check to see if the current user is an Administrator as follows:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'" + $loc
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}
```

The argument for $loc is a parameter that was originally passed via a batch file that is as follows:

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
SET current="%~dp0
START /WAIT powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "JavaInstall.ps1" -loc %current%
```

At the top of the Powershell file, we have:

```
param(
[string]$loc
)
```

This works under two conditions:

1) The user is already an Administrator.
2) The folder this is run from at any point in the traversing does not have a space.

When this is run from a folder such as: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Java Test it suddenly fails. If I Write-Host along the way, I can see that the $loc variable is correct until after the elevation. After it elevates, anything after the space is lost. If I run this directly as an Administrator it of course bypasses the elevation and works even with spaces in the folders, but I do not want to require a right-click run-as scenario. Any ideas what might be causing the loss of text after the space during elevation?

Comment: For the paths with spaces problem, it might be because you're missing a closing quote in this line `SET current="%~dp0`

Comment: What's odd is that anything but a single quote in that spot causes it to cut off anything with spaces even before elevation. I may be using that command incorrectly to begin with though, as that seems odd.

Comment: Maybe just ditch the quotes on that line, and instead wrap `%current%` with them (in the `START` line of the batch).

Comment: Why are you starting the batch script in the first place?  Can you not just call Powershell directly with the correct permissions?

Comment: I thought to run a Powershell script on another computer it was necessary to set the ExecutionPolicy, given we do not have the certifications in place and given the default behavior of Powershell.

Comment: techie007, doing it in this manner did not help and in fact added an extraneous quote during the pre-elevation phase.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with multiple command line parsing here, that's why it's hard to make it work properly. You have to have quotes around your path with spaces when it passed **to** the PowerShell (from the bat file) and when it passed **from** the Powershell (to the Start-Process cmdlet). This means some serious escaping:

1. Remove trailing backslash from the `%~dp0`, or it will mess with with escaping in *P.2*
2. Escape quotes with backslash (`\`) for the `START` command because of [the way the C command line parser works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx):

   > A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash, \",
   >   is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark (").
3. Escape quotes in the PowerShell when using `Start-Process` cmdlet

   1. For the `-File` parameter:

      ```
      "`"$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)`""
      ```
   2. For the `$Loc` argument:

      ```
      "\`"$Loc\`""
      ```

Example below works for me and keeps the path with spaces intact while self-elevating.

Bat launcher :

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

:: Get current directory
SET current=%~dp0

:: Does "current" variable have a trailing slash? If so, remove it
IF %current:~-1%==\ SET current=%current:~,-1%

cd /d %current%

START /WAIT powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "JavaInstall.ps1" -Loc \""%current%\""
```

PowerShell elevation code:

```
Param(
    [string]$Loc
)

$Delay = 5
Write-Host "`$Loc argument: $Loc"

if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(
        [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')
)
{
    Write-Host "Not elevated, restarting in $Delay seconds ..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $Delay

    $Arguments =  @(
        '-NoProfile',
        '-NoExit',
        '-File',
        "`"$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)`"",
        "\`"$Loc\`""
    )
    Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $Arguments
    Break
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Already elevated, exiting in $Delay seconds..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $Delay
}
```